# express-session does not delete session in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

account.js (node.js part)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
  console.log("session: ", req.session);
  req.session.destroy();
  console.log("session: ", req.session);
  res.send(true);
})
```

> session:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTZjZjJiNDY1N2Q3MjQzNzQxMzFjODkiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODQ3MDM3MDF9.A8-gorvV3SI7boHGbtiRh6NXHbnYIR1VnsAzNWwwMTw 
>   session:  undefined

**Purpose:** User login process is successful. If the login is successful, it saves the information to the mongodb field.

[image]

**Problem:** When I write the line of code below, it normally needs to be deleted. But whatever I do, it doesn't delete. You can understand this by examining console.log sections.

If you want to review, I add some of the codes in index.js below.

```
...
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongodDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
const mongoURL = process.env.DB_CONNECT;

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function() {});

const store = new MongodDBStore({
  uri: process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  collection: "sessions"
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
    store: store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 600000,
      sameSite: "strict",
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true
    }
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly=true;Secure=true;SameSite=None");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, PATCH, POST,  DELETE , PUT, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

mongoose.connect(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

This deletion does not cause. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `cookie-parser` module and import it on `index.js` file

```
const cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
```

and set `middleware`

```
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));

//Middleware for session
app.use(session({
   secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
   maxAge: 60000 , // 1min = 60000ms
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true

}));
```